# How do I rotate the x-axis labels in a SAS SGPLOT graph so that they are perpendicular (at 90 degrees to x-axis)

Tags: sas, drawtext

Is it possible to rotate the x-axis labels in SAS SGPLOT so that they are perpendicular (at 90 degrees to x-axis)? The fitpolicy option rotates 45 degrees, but this is not exactly what I need.

SAS code:

```
ods pdf style = custom file='';
proc sgplot data = filename;
series x = date y = unemployment_rate_15_24 / lineattrs = (color = CX963634 thickness = 2 pattern=solid);
series x = date y = unemployment_rate_15_ / lineattrs = (color = CX538DD5 thickness = 2 pattern=solid);
xaxis type=time fitpolicy=rotatethin notimesplit interval=year offsetmax=0 label = ' ' values = ("28FEB1995"d to "28FEB2015"d by year);
yaxis label = ' ' values = (0 to 18 by 2);
x2axis display=(nolabel novalues);
keylegend / location = inside position = topright;
label unemployment_rate_15_24 = "Youth (15-24 years) unemployment rate";
label unemployment_rate_15_ = "Overall (15+ years) unemployment rate";
run;
ods pdf close;
```

I've also tried to  use the Graph Template Language in SAS. Here's the equiavalent code written in GTL:

```
proc template;
define statgraph mysgplot;
begingraph;
layout overlay /
cycleattrs=true 
xaxisopts=(label=" " offsetmax=0 type=time timeopts=(tickvaluelist=(12842 13207 13573 13938 14303 14668 15034 15399 15764 16129 16495 16860 17225 17590 17956 18321 18686 19051 19417 19782 20147) viewmin=12842 viewmax=20147 tickvaluefitpolicy=rotatethin splittickvalue=false interval=year)) 
yaxisopts=(label=" " type=linear linearopts=(tickvaluelist=(0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18) viewmin=0 viewmax=18 )) 
x2axisopts=(display=(ticks line) type=auto);
seriesplot x='date'n y='unemployment_rate_15_24'n / primary=true lineattrs=( color=cx963634 pattern=1 thickness=2) legendlabel="Youth (15-24 years) unemployment rate" NAME="SERIES";
seriesplot x='date'n y='unemployment_rate_15_'n / lineattrs=( color=cx538dd5 pattern=1 thickness=2) legendlabel="Overall (15+ years) unemployment rate" NAME="SERIES1";
discretelegend "SERIES" "SERIES1" / location=inside halign=right valign=top;
endlayout;
endgraph;
end;
run;

proc sgrender data = filename template=mysgplot;
run;
```

Comment: Christian, it would be great if you could add an small example dataset or use one existing in e.g. `SASHELP`.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?

Comment: Just use any data set that you have around... I have EG version 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it's possible to do that in SGPLOT without using annotation.  They have a nice piece of code for doing that with annotation [here](http://support.sas.com/kb/48/432.html).

With GTL, in 9.4 they introduce `TICKVALUEROTATION`, which needs to be used in tandem with `TICKVALUEFITPOLICY=ROTATE|ROTATEALWAYS` and `SPLITTICKVALUE=FALSE`.  See this:

```
data testdata;
  call streaminit(7);
  do timevar = 12900 to 16900 by 500;
    age=10+rand('Normal',5,2);
    output;
  end;
  format timevar date9.;
run;

proc template;
define statgraph mysgplot;
begingraph;
layout overlay /
cycleattrs=true 
xaxisopts=(label=" " offsetmax=0 type=time 
    timeopts=(tickvaluerotation=VERTICAL TICKVALUEFITPOLICY=rotatealways splittickvalue=false) )
yaxisopts=(label=" " type=linear linearopts=(tickvaluelist=(0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18) viewmin=0 viewmax=18 )) 
x2axisopts=(display=(ticks line) type=auto);
seriesplot x=timevar y=age
    / lineattrs=( color=cx538dd5 pattern=1 thickness=2) legendlabel="Overall (15+ years) unemployment rate" NAME="SERIES1";
discretelegend "SERIES" "SERIES1" / location=inside halign=right valign=top;
endlayout;
endgraph;
end;
run;

proc sgrender data = testdata template=mysgplot;
run;
```

I slightly simplify your axis to make sure it works properly, but I think most of your axis statements are okay.

In 9.3 or earlier, I think you're stuck with annotation or 45 degrees.  Or seeing if you can convince a SCATTERPLOT to draw outside of the axes.  Or perhaps using a SERIESPLOT and a SCATTERPLOT to draw your own axes, but that seems a bit over the top.

Here's what the above code looks like:
[image: Rendered Image]

Comment: I get the following error message: ERROR 772-580: Syntax error: expecting a constant or a dynamic. Does this make sense to you Joe?

Comment: Not without context no.

Comment: Well if I just run the proc template I get that error message. Does it work for you? I'm not sure what else to do!

Comment: Yes it did work for me. What line is the error complaining about?  What value?

Comment: when it gets to "timeopts"

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?

Comment: I have EG 4.3. Not sure how to check what version of SAS I have (whether it is 9 or above). I have checked google, but to no avail.

Comment: 4.3 came with 9.2. You probably don't have the version to do this (9.4).  You see what version you have by right click on server and select to view the initialization log.

Comment: OK yes I was just told I have 9.2! Do'h! But we're getting 9.4 in a week so yay!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your code should be useful in a week's time.

Comment: @Joe Haven't gotten around to installing 9.4 yet - still on 9.3 here.  Any chance you would be kind enough to update your answer with an image of the final output as I am currently facing the same issues.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From SAS 9.4 TS1M3, you only need one simple line of code:

```
XAXIS VALUESROTATE=VERTICAL;
```

See: http://support.sas.com/kb/48/432.html