# SAS SGPLOT Creating Angled Date Tick Marks

Tags: date, graph, angle, diagonal, annotate

Hi I am trying to have my dates in the monyy. format on my xaxis, angle upward from right to left at about 45 degrees. I am unable to do this in sgplot. Used to be able to do it fine in an axis statement using angle=45 in gplot. SGPLOT does not recognize this.

I read elsewhere on this site that we could do it through annotation in sgplot. If so, has anyone ever done that with dates? the [SAS site](http://support.sas.com/kb/48/432.html) has some code for text only. Will it work with dates? The [proc template in another string on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763234/how-do-i-rotate-the-x-axis-labels-in-a-sas-sgplot-graph-so-that-they-are-perpend) seems to work but only to angle my dates vertically or diagonally from right to left. I don't think you can angle tick values upward diagonally at 45 degrees unless it's on a 2nd x axis.

Please advise, especially if anyone ever annotated dates to look a specific way on an sgchart or any chart option at all.